# Is it possible to change the can't play error shown to users - Sonos Music API

Tags: sonos

When a track's metadata is set such that canPlay = false users are shown a generic error message saying the track is disabled without any further reasoning. Is it possible in the API to show users a custom error message depending on why the track is disabled?

I can see this article for [handling errors](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/460), but there doesn't seem to be any references to the disabled message (Probably because a user being unable to play a disabled track isn't an error)

Answer (score 0):

When some non-playable tracks get queued up (such as when a playable container has non-playable tracks inside), you should be able to customize the error message by following the error handling instructions you linked to, and returning a custom error message for the getMediaUri call.